# MYSQL- Having with between returns empty result

Tags: mysql, having-clause

Following is the query i am trying to run.

```
SELECT p_date,TS.substationid,ts.substationcode,ts.manufacturingproductid,ts.assemblylineid,ts.teamid,ts.subofficecode,
TA.AllowID,ta.allowname,ta.minbenchmark,ta.maxbenchmark,COUNT(vfp.UnitsPass) Achieved,
            CASE TA.RewardType 
                    WHEN 'Monthly' THEN 
                          TA.RewardValue/DAY(LAST_DAY(P_Date))
                WHEN 'Yearly' THEN
                          TA.RewardValue/((STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM P_Date),1,1),'%Y%m%d')) /(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM P_Date),12,31), '%Y%m%d')))
                WHEN 'Daily' THEN
                          (TA.RewardValue*12)/365           
                 END-- , 0) 
                 AS Allowance
FROM tempsubstation ts
LEFT JOIN TempAllowances ta ON ts.manufacturingproductid=ta.manufacturingproductid AND ts.subofficecode=ta.subofficecode
LEFT JOIN wms_vfproduction vfp ON DATE(vfp.CreationDate)=p_date AND vfp.StationCode='1600150'
WHERE ta.AllowID=41 AND vfp.UnitsPass=1
 GROUP BY p_date,substationcode
 HAVING COUNT(vfp.UnitsPass) BETWEEN ta.minbenchmark AND ta.maxbenchmark
```

Adding having with between starts returning empty results.while when i was comparing it with hard coded values it returns results (again, without between). to keep it generalized i cant use hard coded values and it does not work with between even if i give it hard coded values.

**UPDATE**: Having does not work with between because it already selects a result set with a range where the max is less than the result of COUNT(). However, there is always at least one range with its max greater than the result of COUNT().

Comment: did you try using 'BETWEEN' condition in your 'WHERE' clause.?

Comment: aggregated function will not work in where clause, hence the need of having clause

Comment: try like this : `HAVING COUNT(vfp.UnitsPass) BETWEEN MIN(ta.minbenchmark) AND MAX(ta.maxbenchmark)`

Comment: I made it work. although, your comment did not solve the query right away but it did push me in the right direction. what i was doing wrong was not grouping the result set by ta.minbenchmark and ta.maxbenchmark. hence it would only get the results for the first min-max pair it fines technically making the having clause ineffective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i was doing wrong was not grouping the result set by ta.minbenchmark and ta.maxbenchmark. hence it would only get the results for the first min-max pair it finds technically making the having clause ineffective. So the correct query would be as follows (for anyone making the same mistake):

```
SELECT p_date,TS.substationid,ts.substationcode,ts.manufacturingproductid,ts.assemblylineid,ts.teamid,ts.subofficecode,
TA.AllowID,ta.allowname,ta.minbenchmark,ta.maxbenchmark,COUNT(vfp.UnitsPass) Achieved,
            CASE TA.RewardType 
                    WHEN 'Monthly' THEN 
                          TA.RewardValue/DAY(LAST_DAY(P_Date))
                WHEN 'Yearly' THEN
                          TA.RewardValue/((STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM P_Date),1,1),'%Y%m%d')) /(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM P_Date),12,31), '%Y%m%d')))
                WHEN 'Daily' THEN
                          (TA.RewardValue*12)/365           
                 END-- , 0) 
                 AS Allowance
FROM tempsubstation ts
LEFT JOIN TempAllowances ta ON ts.manufacturingproductid=ta.manufacturingproductid AND ts.subofficecode=ta.subofficecode
LEFT JOIN wms_vfproduction vfp ON DATE(vfp.CreationDate)=p_date AND vfp.StationCode='1600150'
WHERE ta.AllowID=41 AND vfp.UnitsPass=1
 GROUP BY p_date,substationcode,ta.minbenchmark,ta.maxbenchmark
  HAVING COUNT(vfp.UnitsPass) BETWEEN ta.minbenchmark AND ta.maxbenchmark
```

;